# Execute external exe from projector flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

We have a projector application (.exe) compiled from AS3.  How can we start another (external) executable from the projector?

This is the code...it does nothing visible.

```
//Play ACQ Demo
Acq.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickAcq);
function clickAcq(event:MouseEvent):void {
                flash.system.fscommand("exec",".\\ACQ\\Acq.exe");
                trace("ACQ clicked");
                gotoAndPlay("Main");
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation says the program you want to execute should be in an 'fscommand' folder that is next to the projector exe. (You can put a bat file there to start other programs)

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/package.html

Edit: If you want more advanced options you can try a third party tool like http://www.northcode.com/

Comment: 2009. Before permalinks. oh no wait, Adobe still doesn't have permalinks. Hence this one is broken.

Answer (score 1):

This free utility http://www.northcode.com/blog.php/2007/08/07/Conquering-FSCommand-EXEC-Part-1-Proxy lets you work around some of the limitations of the EXEC fscommand in Flash.